# How to setup selendroid in ubuntu 14.04? Cannot execute selendroid script. ANDROID_HOME not found error shown in eclipse console

Tags: bash, java, android, eclipse, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to set up selendroid in ubuntu for mobile app testing purposes.

First I installed JAVA from ubuntu software center.

Then I installed android SDK and I've set path in .bashrc as follows:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
```

I've installed android sdk to opt folder, so the path is as shown above.

I've eclipse Mars.2 installed. In eclispe - using Install new software I've installed Android SDK related plugins and in

Window - Preferences - Android as shown[android-path-set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Mr8.png)

I've created a maven project with testng, selenium-java, selendroid-client, selendroid-standalone in POM.xml and created a sample selendroid test case.

When executed

SEVERE: Error building server: Environment variable 'ANDROID_HOME' was not found!

is shown.

In terminal when I echo $ANDROID_HOME it is showing /opt/android-sdk-linux.

How to fix this issue? Thanks in Advance. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `echo $PATH`? Type this command on your terminal(I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4). After that, you should find Android SDK directory included like:

```
/home/<your-username>/Android/Sdk/tools:...
```

If so is the case, then your `ANDROID_HOME` has been set correctly otherwise it needs to be set. Set the android home variable once again and check if it appears in the result.